# How to move a dom element from a child component to a parent component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have two components, a parent and a child.

Parent Component

```
const Parent = () => {
return (
<>
<div className="container"></div>
<div>more content</div>
<Child/>
</>
)
}
```

Child Component

```
const Child = () => {

const importantFunctionMustBeInChild = () => {
//Does a bunch of stuff that can't be done in the parent due to a lot of state that doesn't make sense to have in the parent
}

return (
<>
<button onClick={importantFunctionMustBeInChild}>Important Button</button>
</>
)
}
```

The problem is that I have a button in the child component. This button renders conditionally based off many different state toggles and has functions that can't be in the parent component because it wouldn't make sense to put it there and would take a long time to move all the state and functions up.

The issue is I now need to have the button to where the `container` div is in the parent component. Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: With React, manipulation of DOM is a BAD idea. instead, based on the condition, add that button to parent and remove from child

Comment: Terrible answer, completely ignores the problem of the question which specifically says that I can't move it to the parent

Comment: "functions that can't be in the parent component" This is a terrible design. A component should be devoid of BL. "Terrible answer, completely ignores the problem" That is the ideal solution. You added a lot of BL in component and now its coming to bite you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the logic, you can assign a value(string, object, array) to parent component's state in the child component, right? So why can you not assign a function to the state and run it on click in the parent?

Definetely you can! In your child, assign function as a reference to the parent's state and thats it!

```
useEffect(() => {
    // assign, don't invoke the function yet!
    setFunctionToExecute(() => importantFunctionMustBeInChild);
}, []);
```

Here's a complete [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/parent-child-functions-3k97rq)